# component is only loaded after the page refreshing in vue js

Tags: api, vue.js, routes, axios

My component is not loaded when it goes login to dashboard. In login method I have used `this.router.push()`. The url is changed but the page not mounted until it refreshes. I have two user so in app.vue I am checking guard and valids the routes depends on the guard. In app.vue here is the code:

```js
methods: {
  isCurrentRouteValid() {
    return this.validRoutes.includes(this.$route.name)
  },
},

computed: {
  validRoutes() {
    this.getActiveGuard = User.getGuard()
    if (this.getActiveGuard == 'admin') {
      return [
        'home',
        'register_admin',
        'login_admin',
        'admin_dashboard',
        'register_manager',
        'login_manager',
        'add_project',
      ]
    } else {
      return [
        'home',
        'login_admin',
        'manager_dashboard',
        'login_manager',
        'register_manager',
        'add_project',
      ]
    }
  },
},
```

Comment: computed property should not do any side effects

Comment: can you elaborate it?

Comment: You should not do any assignment to other properties like `this.getActiveGuard = User.getGuard();`, this makes your property inconsistent

Comment: We're missing a lot of pieces here so we can help you properly. Why do you think your guard system is the one failing? Do you have any errors when navigating?

Comment: no,everything is fine. just component loades after refreshes if I swithc admin to manager guard.

Comment: As it was mentioned, you should not do side effects in computed properties (read here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#best-practices). In this case (even if it is only barely described), I would think, that `this.getActiveGuard = User.getGuard()` should be called in the `mounted` function. I recommend you might want to look into the Vue documentation and learn about [how computed properties work](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html).

Comment: I have deleted this side effects in computed properties and it didn't change anything. I have fixed this in different way.